# Apply same style for all

Tags: microsoft-word

I have MS Word document that contains section marked as Heading2. Each section contains table and some text around it. Is it possible somehow organize document when I change font in table MS Word applies this change for all tables automatically.

I would like to apply this rule also for text near tables without changing text font in tables and sections.

How to achieve that?

Comment: Look into Table Styles.

Answer (score 1):

As Charles already mentioned, you will have to work with table styles and paragraph styles.

1. Click into a table, go to the "Table Design" tab and click on the little "More" arrow of the "Table Styles" section.

[image]

2. At the bottom select "New Table Style"

[image]

3. Before changing the formatting, choose whether you want to apply the formatting changes to the whole table or only a part of a table (e.g. Header Row)

[image]

4. Set your desired formatting and click on "OK".
5. Apply the newly created style to the tables you want
6. If you want to automate the process after creating the table style, you can also use a Macro for that purpose:

```
Dim t As Table
 For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
 t.Style = "Custom Table Style Name" 
Next
```